# Where is Empty Code First Model in Entity Data Model Wizard?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using `Visual Studio 2010` and want to use `EF Code First` as `ORM`. I cant find that template in `Entity Data Model Wizard` as it is in [this thread](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/model-first-with-entity-framework.aspx). Yes, I installed `Nuget Package Manager` and `Entity Framework 6.2` for my project. Can't I use code first approach in my project? what is there to be additionally installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entity Data Model Wizard refers to model first, if you want to use code first, then you will design your POCO classes firstly, and use your classes to generate database for you. HTH.

Comment: What extension of my DBfile will be? edmx or mdf?

Comment: If you want to use code first, there is no edmx file involved. Your db file will just normal sql database file.